# Search mails using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

we are using microsoft graph api list and send emails. The new requirement is to search emails. When following URL is tried then we are getting errors. Can someone suggest if this is the right api to search mails messages? or what kind of permissions are missing?

URL : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query`   ([documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages))

Error using following request body : `"Application permission is only supported for the following entity types:site, list, listItem, drive and driveItem."`

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "message"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": "hello"
      },
      "region": "NAM",
      "from": 0,
      "size": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

Error returned::

```
"code": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": "Application permission is only supported for the following entity types:site, list, listItem, drive and driveItem.",
        "target": "",
        "httpCode": 403
```

When tried to change the body to get list, as expected it did not return list, as we have only mail.readwrite permissions.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
          "listItem"
      ],
       "query": {
        "queryString": "contoso"
      },
      "region": "NAM",
       "sharePointOneDriveOptions": {
           "includeContent": "privateContent,sharedContent"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Error Returned:

```
"code": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": "Access to ListItem in Graph API requires the following permissions: Sites.Read.All or Sites.ReadWrite.All. However, the application only has the following permissions granted: Mail.ReadWrite, Mail.Read",
        "target": "",
        "httpCode": 403
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc - [Known limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages#known-limitations) , You can access only the signed-in user’s own mailbox. Searching delegated mailboxes is not supported. try to write query to search your own message.
[image]

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: When a mailbox is accessed via Graph API client ID+ secret key, is it different than own mailbox? I am bit confused with own mailbox vs Delegated mailbox vs mailbox access via graph api !